# What is the best way to prevent FOUC on a jquery ui button?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a page with a few buttons on it that have a class on them. When the page loads I am using jQuery UI .button function inside a ready function to turn these buttons into jquery UI buttons.

I want these buttons to look exactly the same when the page is loading as they do when the page is fully loaded. However currently, they look very ugly while loading and then pop to the jquery ui button look once the page is fully loaded.

I have tried adding the following to the class, which styles them correctly except for the padding,

```
ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all
```

Is adding these classes to the button the best way to style the button ahead of time? Or is there a better way to fix this issue?

Comment: Not sure but you may be able to use holdReady to delay the ready event while running the .button function... http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are making all your buttons jQuery UI buttons, you could initially hide all the buttons, like the following:

```
button, input[type=button] /* and others, e.g. submit, reset, anchors */
{ visibility: hidden; }
```

And when rendering the button you show them, e.g.

```
$(':button, :submit, :reset')
  .button()
  .css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"})
  .animate({opacity: 1.0});
```

Comment: This is a nice alternative. Of course you did get the suddenly appearing buttons effect, but it does highlight available functionality.

Comment: @Peter, that can be easily remedied by adding an effect for show, e.g. `.show(1000)`, `.fadeIn()`.

Comment: It's often nicer to use `visibility: hidden`, so at least the layout is static and doesn't jump around when buttons show themselves.

Comment: @numbers..., good point! It'd be a bit more tricky to animate visibility... I have updated the answer.

Comment: This is another one I thought about, but the buttons will get loaded at a later time in this instance. I it still another great option. Just gotta get the best trade offs.

Answer (score 1):

That is probably the best way.

You should inspect your layout in firebug after jquery UI adds all of its classes (to make sure you're not missing any), and hardcode all of those classes to your elements ahead of time.

The only potential problem arises if you're dynamically setting focus to certain jq-ui elements on pageload. For example, you wouldn't want element 1 hardcoded to "ui-active" state if the url specifies element 3.

Comment: Cool, thats sorta what I was thinking, but it feels very hackish having to add these classes to all of the buttons.

Comment: yeah, it kind of is. but jquery ui isn't instant so we do what we must :)